# What extra pieces of data does a function make when called

Tags: function, memory

When a function is called it creates space in memory for the data it'll be handling. When it does this it creates some space for the variables in it and for the list of commands it'll perform. What other bits of data is stored in memory?

I believe there's one piece to describe where the CPU should return to after executing the function. What is that piece of data called?